# If $X$ has density, when has $X\cdot I_A$ a density?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space, and $X$ be a random variable with some density function $f_X$. If $A \in \mathcal F$, then the indicator function $I_A$ has, as a discrete random variable, no densitiy function, but does $X\cdot I_A$ has a densitiy function (of course I can image cases where it has not, for example if $X\cdot I_A \equiv 0$, but does there exist cases where it has, and if so how does the density $f_{X\cdot I_A}$ look like?).

For the induced measure $P_{X\cdot I_A}(B) := P((X\cdot I_A)^{-1}(B))$ I think we must have:
$$
 P_{X\cdot I_A} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
 P(\Omega \setminus A) + P(X^{-1}(B)\cap A) &, ~ 0 \in B \\
 P(X^{-1}(0)\cap A) &, ~ 0 \notin B 
 \end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: $f_{X\Bbb 1_A}$ would not integrate to 1. I think you really want $f_{X|A}$

Comment: To what value does it integrate, what do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\mathbb{P}(1_A X \in B) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{P}(A \cap \{X \in B\}) + \mathbb{P}(A^c), & 0 \in B, \\ \mathbb{P}(A \cap \{X \in B\}), & 0 \notin B \end{cases}$$

for any Borel set $B$. In particular, for $B := \{0\}$, we get

$$\mathbb{P}(1_A X \in B)>0$$

whenever $\mathbb{P}(A^c) \neq 0$. Since $B=\{0\}$ is a Lebesgue null-set, this means that $1_A X$ does **not** have a density (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) if $\mathbb{P}(A^c) \neq 0$. On the other hand, if $\mathbb{P}(A^c)=0$ (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$), then $X \cdot 1_A = X$ has density $f$.